# Do kotlin inline function have code branch inlining if parameter is fixed?

Tags: kotlin, inline

Let say I have this function:

```kotlin
inline fun run(type: Int, block: (String) -> Unit) {
    when(type) {
        Scenario.A -> { block("A") }
        Scenario.B -> { block("B") }
    }
}
```

And later on I call :

```kotlin
run(Scenario.A) { println(it) } 
run(Scenario.B) { println(it) }
```

Will it translates to:

```kotlin
println("A")
println("B")
```

or

```kotlin
when(Scenario.A) {
    Scenario.A -> { println("A") }
    Scenario.B -> { println("B") }
}
when(Scenario.B) {
    Scenario.A -> { println("A") }
    Scenario.B -> { println("B") }
}
```

Comment: If you go Tools -> Kotlin in IntelliJ IDEA you can view the bytecode.

Comment: It will probably translate to the latter but does it really matter? Probably not.

Comment: I'm not proficient in reading bytecode.. I'll look into it when I have time, thanks. I was just curious about what's the behavior of such case.

Comment: Even if it's not inlined in the bytecode, the JVM is very smart and AIUI can easily inline things like that on-the-fly.

Comment: Pretty sure it’s the second one, but then the JVM takes care of the rest like gidds said.